# How to get current date -1 in mysql in given format in mysql?

Tags: mysql

based on below query how to get last date in given format

```
select date_format(current_Date,'%d/%m/%y %h:%i %p')  from dual
```

format should be matched as mentioned.

Comment: Your question title says "max date" but your question mentions the current date.  Which do you want, and can you add sample data to your question?

Comment: Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1):

- You can get **Current** datetime value using [`Now()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function.
- Now, you can subtract **1 day** from it, using [`Date_add()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function.

Try the following:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), '%d/%m/%y %h:%i %p') FROM dual
```

**Output**:

```
| DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), '%d/%m/%y %h:%i %p') |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------ |
| 28/10/18 06:32 AM                                                  |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tNKcqiYuMgwZuVb7bg4axo/0)

Comment: 6.32? Someone's a bit keen

Comment: @Strawberry I hope so, but not really! Results are in UTC, while I am in IST.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer the written out form of date arithmetic:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%d/%m/%y %h:%i %p') FROM dual
```

Output

```
28/10/18 06:33 AM
```

If you want the time part to be reset to midnight, use [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) instead:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%d/%m/%y %h:%i %p') FROM dual
```

Output

```
28/10/18 12:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [DATE_SUB()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function.

Try the following:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%d/%m/%y %h:%i %p') FROM dual
```

Output:

`28/10/18 03:04 PM`